# jQuery nested clone loop with using select box append

Tags: jquery

I am a beginner in jQuery. I don't know about nested loops. I am stuck on the first loop.

I have two issues.

I explained my questions in below screenshots.

```
   $( document ).ready(function() {

        var current_id = 0;
        $('#btn').click(function(){
            if(current_id < 4)
                nextElement($('#Outer_00'));
        })

        function nextElement(element){
            var newElement = element.clone();
            var id = current_id+1;
            current_id = id;
            if(id <10)id = "0"+id;
            newElement.attr("id",element.attr("id").split("_")[0]+"_"+id);
            var field = $('select', newElement).attr("id");
            $('select', newElement).attr("id", field.split("_")[0]+"_"+id );
            newElement.appendTo($("#elements"));
        }

    });



<div id="elements">
<button id="btn">Add</button>
    <div id="Outer_00" class="boxbg">
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="text">
    <select id="Field1_00"><option>element1</option><option>Next level</option></select>


    </div>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/swaroop206/ddg1kg4u/

Comment: Can you please be more specific about your issue . its not clear with the images